# Solidity keyword delete is not working

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, mapping

I have used the keyword **delete** to delete mapping and array  in Remix a couple of months ago,
But now I have just noticed that the keyword **delete** is not working at all.

Does anybody know the reason why it is not working?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Ex {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    uint[] public array = [97,98,99];
    function addBalance(address _key,uint newBalance) public {
        balances[_key] = newBalance;
    }

    function deleteBalance(address _key) public {
        delete balances[_key];
    }
    
    function deleteArray(uint _index) public {
       delete array[_index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just a remix's problem, I have tried it in truffle it was totally okay.
I have just opened the issue in the remix github.

Comment: Thanks, I too, tried to figure out what was wrong here, and couldn't figure it out. For some reason, it always returns "out of Gas" whenever I try to delete.

Comment: Np :), Good news!, it is fixed, now it is working!